# pyqt check if value of lineEdit changed

Tags: pyqt, android-edittext, line

I Need to check if the value of a lineEdit in PyQt4 changed, if this value is changed I Need to Trigger a Slot.
My code:

```
self.connect(self.ui.lineEdit, QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged (QString & text"), self.sync_lineEdit)
```

Nothing happend if I Change the value in the GUI.
Any idea how to fix this Problem?

Kind regards;

Comment: You are using the old style of signal/slot connection. See the pyqt documentation (and qurban's answer) for how to connect using the new (pythonic) style of connecting sigals and slots: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try simple connect:

```
self.ui.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.sync_lineEdit)
...

def sync_lineEdit(self, text):
    print text
```

This should work fine

Comment: Note that the `textChanged` signal is emitted every time the text is changed. This includes changes made programmatically using `setText`. To only react to changes made by the user you can use the `textEdited` signal instead.